# Chrome Save as PDF changing CJK characters

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, unicode

We are seeing an issue when we try to save a webpage containing CJK characters as a PDF using Chrome's Print option.

The character rendered by chrome in the PDF visually looks the same but the Unicode is different.

Below is a basic HTML.

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  Test Character
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  子
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

The character if the HTML is opened in chrome is
 https://graphemica.com/%E5%AD%90

But the corresponding character in PDF is
 https://graphemica.com/%E2%BC%A6

Link for the HTML and PDF
https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aq5YnvMOo4V8iVzdRyjmX3X5L0TD

Firstly I would want to understand why this is happening and then what can be the workaround for the same. Is there any utility which can convert my Character into what Chrome is going to render it in PDF.

OS Version : MacOS 10.13.6 (17G65)

Chrome Version : 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Corresponding chromium issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=981259

Comment: Cannot reproduce, tested with Chromium 75.0.3770.100 and Okular 1.7.2 on openSUSE Tumbleweed. Character in both HTML and PDF is `U+5B50 ‹子› \N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5B50}`, as expected. – There's some information missing. How do you determine that you get `U+2F26 ‹⼦› \N{KANGXI RADICAL CHILD}` in the PDF? Can you upload a copy?

Comment: @daxim Attached the HTML and the PDF link. After opening the PDF in chrome, I am doing ctrl+P and then selecting save as PDF

Comment: That PDF clearly contains U+5B50. You still haven't said how you determine that you have that other character in the PDF. This is a waste of time.

Comment: @daxim I appreciate that you are trying to help. I am assuming you just previewed it in Onedrive, that's why you are seeing U+5B50. Apologies for the confusion. 
If you download the PDF, open it either in Chrome or Adobe Reader, you can just copy the character, paste it here
https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter
You will see the resultant character is 
\u2f26

Let me know if you are able to view the same Unicode.

Comment: I apologise for my abrasive expression. I now have tested all the PDF viewers/renderers/tools available to me. They are of divided opinion, frankly I think that's bizarre. **U+5B50**: okular 1.7.2, xreader 1.8.5, Firefox 67 **U+2F26**: qpdfview 0.4.16, pdfgrep 2.0.1, Chromium 75, pdftotext/poppler-tools 0.72.0

Comment: U+5B50 is the Unicode normalization compatibility decomposition form (NFKD) of U+2F26, but not vice versa.  So if you started with U+5B50 none of the Unicode normalization forms change it to U+2F26, so change to U+2F26 is odd.

Comment: Yep. U+5B50 is not changing when normalized. U+2F26 is normalizing to U+5B50, but only in NFKC and NFKD. Weird.

Comment: If what @daxim says is true, and the different PDF renderers are rendering it differently, this may well not be an issue with the output PDF. Can anybody confirm that a PDF with the U+5B50 character renders as the U+5B50 character?

Comment: Looks like a software bug in the PDF viewer. I don't see a viable workaround. Although you could call replace all instances of U+5B50 with U+2F26, this will cause issues if the unicode is normalized by Chrome when the PDF is downloaded (possible, haven't tested), or if the unicode is normalized by another PDF viewer.

Comment: @ecc521 Incorrect, Chrome is saving the PDF with U+2F26 on MacOS, and U+5B50 on other platforms (I tested Windows and Linux): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch5Z2.png

Comment: It looks like any attempts to solve this problem are probably futile. Good luck on that bug report.

Comment: I would advise dealing with the reality that, at least for the time being, the unicode composition of your website will be different than that of the rendered PDF. If the user is pasting text from the rendered PDF into an application you control, you can normalize all text entered into your application to either NFKC or NKFD.

Comment: Unicode Normalization reference (mostly for Javascript): https://withblue.ink/2019/03/11/why-you-need-to-normalize-unicode-strings.html

Comment: Skia dev here.
The tracking bug is here: http://crbug.com/738643

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that a PDF does not actually contain the string of characters you see when the document is rendered, but rather sequences of font glyphs and supporting lookup tables that map those glyphs back to character codes. In OP's test case, the font utilized for the cjk character on macOS is `STSongti-SC-Regular` and its glyph id is hex `0436`.

I can only reproduce OP's behavior on macOS. On both Linux and Windows, I see the glyph mapped to the character that was originally in the html file: `U+5B50`. An example comparison is shown below in output from the [`peepdf`](https://github.com/jesparza/peepdf) utility:

[image]

The operations to go from character-to-glyph and glyph-to-character are done in the [`onCharsToGlyphs()`](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/793818b23573178b967f5d213163236d56e4ec7b/src/ports/SkFontHost_mac.cpp#L2408) and [`populate_glyph_to_unicode()`](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/793818b23573178b967f5d213163236d56e4ec7b/src/ports/SkFontHost_mac.cpp#L1661) methods of skia's `SkFontHost_mac.cpp` respectively. On macOS, both of these rely on calls to [`CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1510813-ctfontgetglyphsforcharacters) from the Core Text lib, iterating through every possible character to build the mapping tables.

I boiled that approach down to following test code, printing out each glyph id and corresponding character code for a given font:

```
NSString *fontName = @"STSongti-SC-Regular";
CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)fontName, 10.0, NULL);

CFDataRef bitmap = CFCharacterSetCreateBitmapRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, CTFontCopyCharacterSet(fontRef));
CFIndex length = CFDataGetLength(bitmap);

const UInt8* bits = CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmap);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    int mask = bits[i];
    if (!mask)
        continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        CGGlyph glyph;
        UniChar unichar = (UniChar)((i << 3) + j);
        if (mask & (1 << j) && CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(fontRef, &unichar, &glyph, 1)) {
            NSLog(@"%04x %04x", glyph, unichar);
        }
    }
}
```

Looking through the output, there are two character codes for our glyph code:

```
0436 2f26
0436 5b50
```

It encounters `2f26` first, which is significant because when building the lookup table, if a character code has already been determined for a glyph (and its value is >= `0x20`), it [does not get overwritten](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/793818b23573178b967f5d213163236d56e4ec7b/src/ports/SkFontHost_mac.cpp#L1647):

```
if (CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, utf16, glyphs, count)) {
    // ...
    if (glyphToUnicode[glyphs[0]] < 0x20) {
        glyphToUnicode[glyphs[0]] = codepoint;
    }
}
```

So, ultimately what I believe is happening is:

1. Chrome correctly determines the `STSongti-SC-Regular` glyph id for `5B50` to be `0436`. It uses this glyph for the cjk character in the pdf.
2. Then, it builds the glyph-to-charcode lookup table for `STSongti-SC-Regular` by iterating through all possible characters. Since `0436` maps to two codes and it encounters `2f26` first, that's what gets recorded, and is the value that is returned when copying and pasting from the document.

Comment: To complete the loop, if somebody is trying to read these PDFs programmatically. Python has a normalize function to convert the characters into standard values. 

https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize

For the above-mentioned character, the form value should be "NFKD".